# C#: Can't get value of cells in grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

```
GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text
```

Why can't I get the value of the cell in grid view.
Instead, it is giving me "&nbsp"

Comment: Provide code details for what event and which cell you want to retrieve its value. `&nbsp` is non-breaking space HTML code that indicates blank cell inside `GridView` control.

Comment: this could be because adding spaces to text when entering data

Answer (score 0):

**You can Try code**

```
string str;
str = DataGridView1.Rows[DataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Index].Cells[X].Value.ToString();
```

Or

```
textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[X].Value.ToString();
```